# WSO2-AM 3.2.0 - Make sure your API invocation call has a header: testkey is missing

Tags: jwt, wso2-api-manager

I've published an API in WSO2 AM and now, when I try to test the API by curl, passing the token, it shows an error:

curl request:

```
curl -X GET "https://192.168.21.120:8243/ms-authorization/1.0.0/authorization/access-type/access-type" 
-H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ4NXQiOiJNell4TW1Ga09HWXdNV0kwWldObU5Er0m9eU..
-iNxXl0D9to5ptemrd42itirPDJiYJJ_FkSMKSfQ6m78X2fr-Tag" -k
```

response:

```
{"fault":{"code":900902,"message":"Missing Credentials","description":"Authentication Error. Make sure your API invocation call has a header: testkey is missing"}}
```

Why is expecting a "testkey" in header?

Comment: Did you set custom auth header as explained in this doc? - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-oauth2-tokens/#customizing-the-authorization-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just enabled CORS configuration, redeployed the API and everything worked:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to test the API using the Publisher Test Console, you need to include the generated access token/test key in your curl with the header `testkey`.

eg:

```
curl -X GET "https://localhost:8243/napi/1.0/*" -H "accept: */*" -H "testkey: 032456ff-4764-4321-2348-e7ad1ac5t6g0" -k
```

Comment: No, I'm testing using terminal and even so it asks for testkey.

Comment: If you have published the API, subscribed to it with an app, and generated a token from that app, you can use it with the Authorization header to invoke the API. Test key is usually used when API is invoked through Publisher console when its in prototyped state. Both can be done in terminal. You need to provide the appropriate header.

Comment: The Application is in production state. I've tried passing this header `Authorization: Bearer <JWT>`. I already did a test by console and the header changed to `testkey: <JWT>`. But now is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

simple resolution for this is to go to a lifecycle in API manager and
click redeploy. It will work

[image]